# How can I create a localStorage string that can be used to add values inside it, like a list?

Tags: c#, list, blazor, local-storage

This is my code,I am setting up an empty localStorage string,but later I want to push values inside this localStorage string,and then check if the current input is inside this localStorage string.This is written inside the index.razor page in an almost blank BlazorWebAssemblyApp.I want to add values(ids) inside this localStorage string and then check if some of them were already there.

```
<EditForm Model="@data" OnSubmit="HandleLogin" class="login-form">
   
    
     <input type="text" class="form-control" @bind=@data.Id @bind:event="oninput" placeholder="Enter ID" name="psw" id="psw" required>
   
    
            <button type="submit" class="loginlink" >Log in</button>
         
    
 </EditForm>


 private DataModel data = new DataModel();

 protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
     data = new DataModel();
     return base.OnInitializedAsync();
 }

 List<string> idslist = new List<string>();

 private async void HandleLogin()
 {

     var currentId = await LocalStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("id");
     var curentsmscode = await LocalStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("smscode");
     var curenttoken = await LocalStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("Token");
     **var idslistcurr = await LocalStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("studentsInfo");**


     if (currentId == data.Id && data.Id.Length >= 4 && curentsmscode!=null && curenttoken!=null)
     {

         Console.WriteLine("Already logged in!");

         await Task.Delay(1500);


         Console.Write(string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, ids));

         NavManager.NavigateTo("/enviar");

     }
     else 
     {


         if (data.Id != null && data.Id.Length >= 4)
         {

             string usersid = data.Id;
             ids.Add(usersid);
             var randomId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

             **idslist.Add(data.Id);

             await LocalStorage.SetItemAsync("studentsInfo",(idslist));**

             Console.WriteLine("New User Welcome!");

            
             await LocalStorage.SetItemAsync<string>("id", data.Id);
             await LocalStorage.SetItemAsync<string>("userId", randomId);
             await AuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();

             NavManager.NavigateTo("/verificar");

         }
         else if(curentsmscode==null)
         {

             var usersid = data.Id;
             var user = users.Where(x => x.Id == usersid).First();


             await LocalStorage.SetItemAsync<string>("id", data.Id);
             await LocalStorage.SetItemAsync<string>("userId", user.UserId);
             await AuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();

             Console.WriteLine("Logged In!");

             NavManager.NavigateTo("/verificar");

         }
         else if (data.Id == null || data.Id.Length < 4)
         {
             errorMessage2 = true;
         }


         Console.Write(string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, ids));
         Console.Write(string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, idscur));
     }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GetItemAsync<List<string>>` instead of `GetItemAsync<string>`:

`var idslistcurr = await LocalStorage.GetItemAsync<List<string>>("studentsInfo");`